# Trying to differentte $\ln(|2+f(x)|)=2+e^{x*x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

I am trying to solve this differential

$\ln(|2+f(x)|)=2+e^{x*x}$

so far I did this much;
$$
\ln(|2+f(x)|)=2+e^{x*x}\\
|2+f(x)|=e^{2+e^{x*x}}\\
\text{now I have two situations/solutions, because of absolute value}\\
|2+f(x)|>=0\\
\text{where I got that}\\
f(x)=e^{2+{e^{x*x}}}-2\\
|2+f(x)|<0\\
\text{where I got that}\\
f(x)=-e^{2+{e^{x*x}}}-2\\
\text{and this is strange, because the solution is $f(x)=-e^{2+{e^{x*x}}}+2$}
$$

I am doing something wrong or are the solutions in the book wrong??? Thanks

Comment: Yes, in the first step. $\ln(a)=b$ implies $a=e^b$. So if $\ln|2+f(x)|=2+e^{x*x}$ then $|2+f(x)|=e^{2+e^{x*x}}$.

Comment: @Richard thanks for the reply , but I don't see the difference, of what you and what I h+have wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct,though you could check if they wrote $\ln(|2+f(x)|)=2+e^{x*x}$ or $|\ln(2+f(x))|=2+e^{x*x}$
$$\ln(|2+e^{2+e^{x*x}}-2|)\\\ln(|e^{2+e^{x*x}}|)\\\ln(e^{2+e^{x*x}})=2+e^{x*x}\\\ln(|2-{e^{2+e^{x*x}}-2|)}\\\ln(|-e^{2+e^{x*x}}|)\\\ln(e^{2+e^{x*x}})=2+e^{x*x}$$

Comment: it is written like $\ln(|\text{equation}|)$.Thanks for help